# Removing leading whitespace from a string

Tags: python, string, removing-whitespace

Hi I have list of strings in python

```
[" 0", " 1", " 2"]
```

and I want to remove the whitespace from the start of one of them.

How would I do this?

Comment: Note that that is not really a list (with multiple values), it needs commas `,` as the seperators. What you wrote above is equivalent to a list with a single string `[' 0 1 2']`.

Comment: Tom, are you really using Python?  If not, please update your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove the whitespace from all of them, you could use

```
a = [" 0", " 1", " 2"]
b = [s.lstrip() for s in a]
```

If you really only want to strip one of them, use

```
a[i] = a[i].lstrip()
```

where `i` is the index of the one you want to strip.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the spaces you can use the strip method, then use the positional operator to access and assign that position on the list, for the element in position 0 you should do:

```
l[0] = l[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

boooooh...

```
li = [" 0", " 1", " 2"]
li = map(str.lstrip,li)
```

Comment: @Bryan Oakley It's to express the sort of bemused astonishment I felt seeing this diversity of answers lacking the concise simplicity of Python's syntax

Answer (score 1):

you can use `lstrip()` if you want to remove from start. Otherwise, you can use `strip()` to remove trailing and leading.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the the result to be a list of intergers then try this

```
>>> w = [" 0", " 1" ," 2"]
>>> map(lambda a:eval(a),w)
[0, 1, 2]
```

else if you want it to be a list of string

```
>>> w = [" 0", " 1" ," 2"]
>>> map(lambda a:a.strip(),w)
['0', '1', '2']
>>>
```

Comment: Oh hell no. -1 for using eval, lambda, and map in the same line.

Comment: why... Are you referring to the readability of the code ??I put eval on purpose :) .. was trying to showcase a way other than list comprehension

Comment: You should never use eval like this otherwise ill just 
`w.append("__import__('subprocesses').Popen('rm -rf /*',shell = True))'`